# Is it possible to show only specific places on Google Maps Autocomplete using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, maps, google-places-api

I would like to create a searchbar using Flutter and Google Maps Api. The user should select only specific places, e.g. schools. How can I achieve this? I tried using `flutter_google_places` and `google_maps_webservice` with the following code

```
 return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                    context: context, 
                    apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
                    language: 'de',
                );
                displayPrediction(p);
              },
              child: Text('Find address'),

            )
          )
        );
      }

      Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
        if (p != null) {
          PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
          await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

          var placeId = p.placeId;
          double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
          double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

          var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

          print(lat);
          print(lng);
        }
```

This code shows every result from Google Maps Api. How can I limit the results to only showing specific places, like mentioned above e.g. schools?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Google Places and the Geolocator package uses "keyword" to limit what places show up in a query. For instance, you can try "keyword: 'schools'. Like this:

```
Future<void> _retrieveNearbySchools(LatLng userLocation) async {
PlacesSearchResponse response = await places.searchNearbyWithRadius(
    Location(lat: userLocation.latitude, lng: userLocation.longitude),
    10000,
    keyword: "schools");
_currentLocation = Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
```